Anime/cartoon on Cartoon Network channel where a boy follows a girl to a magical world
The first thing I remember is a school class, where the main character enters the class bumping into a girl. The girl can travel into a magical world with a big magical red gem. The boy (main character) accidentally follows the girl in the magical world. As they enter the magical world, their mini doll were created. The boy gets black armour and fights evil and become a hero, but in the present world his dolls were tortured. I saw this on the Cartoon Network channel.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when did you watch this?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are a good opportunity to [edit] in information that has come to light, e.g. "I know that it isn't A Massachusetts Yankee in King Candy's Court because the protagonist was black, and the girl was only two feet tall in her world while the protagonist showed up at his regular size."

Is it possible that you're thinking of The Toy Warrior as per Cartoon movie about a boy student and a new girl student who is the princess of a secret toy world?


The Land Of Toys is a world of pure imagination, ruled by the popular doll Princess Sherbet, but when the mysterious Dark One threatens Sherbet's toy kingdom, she turns to the real world in search of a heroic Warrior Prince... Unfortunately, she ends up with the imaginative trouble-maker Jinoo. When Jinoo accidentally touches Sherbet's magical Warrior Stone, the spunky sixth-grader is suddenly transported to the Land Of Toys to become the powerful Toy Warrior! Aided by the reluctant Princess Sherbet, the transforming Police-bot, R.J., and Jinoo's amazingly loyal backpack, Ping, Jinoo is ready to play Toy Warrior and chase the dark forces across the landscape of imagination. The evil is spreading and now both the real world and the very Well of Imagination itself are at stake! Our only hope is a hero with heart... the Toy Warrior Jinoo!

Not matching, it's a blue gem that she's carrying that he touches:

And his armor his more of a light blue than black.

As per the copyright on this image, it seems that Cartoon Network did broadcast it at some point.
